# Can't get my character to double jump in Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

So we're currently trying learning about 2D platformers in class and one of the tasks is to perform a double jump.

What I tried to do is set up two booleans, one to tell if the character is off the ground and another to see if the double jump has been used or not.

Once you press the Z key for the first time it makes it so the character it turns the first boolean off and the second turns off when we use the second one.

I've tried a few things and I just can't get it to actually double jump, only do a single jump.

Here's what the code for the jumps looks like

Declarations of Booleans:

```
public var isOnGround:Boolean;
public var canDoubleJump:Boolean;
```

this is where we actually do the jump

```
        if ( FlxG.keys.justPressed("Z"))
        {
            if (isOnGround)
            {
                play("jump");
                velocity.y = -JUMP_SPEED;
                isOnGround = false;
            }

            if (canDoubleJump && !isOnGround)
            {
                play("jump");
                velocity.y = -JUMP_SPEED;
                isOnGround = false;
                canDoubleJump = false;
            }
        }
```

Finally, this is how it looks when we finally land on the ground to reset everything

```
        if ( !velocity.y && isTouching( DOWN ) )
        {
            isOnGround = true;
            canDoubleJump = true;
        }
```

To add I am using Flixl for this project. Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that your double jump will always happen at the same time as your first jump. Both those if statements will run on the first jump.

Let's look at the code: (annotated with comments)

```
        //First jump (both jump flags isOnGround and canDoubleJump are true)

        //first jump, this is true
        if (isOnGround)
        {
            play("jump");
            velocity.y = -JUMP_SPEED;
            isOnGround = false;  //your setting this to false now, which makes the next if statement evaluate true as well (even though it shouldn't)
        }

        //since you set isOnGround to false in the above if statement, this if statement will also succeed on the first jump
        if (canDoubleJump && !isOnGround)
        {
            play("jump");
            velocity.y = -JUMP_SPEED;
            isOnGround = false;  //no point in this line, you already know it's false from the if statement
            canDoubleJump = false;
        }
```

To remedy this, you need to NOT do the second `if` when the first one succeeds.   Best way to do that, would be to check for the double jump first:

```
//first jump, isOnGround is true, so this WON'T run
if (canDoubleJump && !isOnGround)
{
    play("jump");
    velocity.y = -JUMP_SPEED;
    canDoubleJump = false;
}

//first jump, this will run,  second jump it will be false
if (isOnGround)
{
    play("jump");
    velocity.y = -JUMP_SPEED;
    isOnGround = false;
}
```

Comment: somehow my comment deleted---

After first successfully double jump, it will only validate second condition because reset code set isOnGround to true.

Comment: Thank you so much, I can't believe I missed something so simple!